Start an older version 3.5.26 of Neo4J in Neo4J Desktop
I want to deploy an older Neo4J database (version 3.5.26) on a new server. I tried to set it up with Neo4J Desktop, but the oldest versions available in the drop down is 4.x.
Is there a way to deploy an older version in the current Neo4J Desktop app?
Or maybe someone can point me to a resource where I can find the older CE version of 3.5.26 with a Windows GUI to start the database?
Thanks
